# Image doesn't show up in outlook when sending email with Python

Tags: python, image, email, outlook

I am trying to send an email with Python with an inline image.

I wrote a script:

```
from pretty_html_table import build_table
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message['Subject'] = f"Data for {last_date.date()}"
message['From'] = sender
message['To'] = receiver

# Builds HTML Table
output_table = build_table(table_for_email, "blue_light")

text = MIMEText(
    f'''<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello!</p>
    <p>Please check out the new data.</p>
    {output_table}
    <img src="cid:plots">
  </body>
</html>
''', "html"
)
message.attach(text)
image = MIMEImage(open('figure.png', 'rb').read())

image.add_header('Content-ID', '<plots>')
message.attach(image)

attach_file_name = 'figure.png'
attach_file = open(attach_file_name, 'rb')
payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octate-stream')
payload.set_payload((attach_file).read())
encoders.encode_base64(payload)
payload.add_header('Content-Decomposition', 'attachment', filename=attach_file_name)
message.attach(payload)

msg_body = message.as_string()

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(mail_server)
server.login(sender, password)
server.sendmail(from_addr=sender, 
                to_addrs=receiver, 
                msg=msg_body)

server.quit()
```

When I open an email with Gmail, it shows the image, but it does not in Outlook client.
[image]

I have unchecked "Don't download pictures automatically..." in Outlook trust center, but still it doesn't work. Looks like it download the files (shows in progress bar) but doesn't show them in email priview.

Comment: It seems Outlook can't locate the image. Have you tries to use any tools such MFCMAPI to check whether a corresponding attachment exists on the email?

Comment: Eugene thanks for the answer, I didn't try that, but still solved the problem and will post it now.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using EmailMessage library instead of email.mime...

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid
from pretty_html_table import build_table
import smtplib
import imghdr

output_table = build_table(table_for_email, "blue_light")

newMessage = EmailMessage()
newMessage['Subject'] = f"Data for {last_date.date()}"
newMessage['From'] = sender
newMessage['To'] = receiver

newMessage.set_content('Hello, please check the new data.')

figure_id = make_msgid()
newMessage.add_alternative("""\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello, please check the new data.</p>
""" + output_table + """
    <img src="cid:{figure_id}" />
  </body>
</html>
""".format(figure_id=figure_id[1:-1]), subtype='html')

# Inline image
with open("figure.png", 'rb') as img:
    newMessage.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(), 'image', 'png',
                                     cid=figure_id)

# Image as attachment
with open('figure.png', 'rb') as f:
    image_data = f.read()
    image_type = imghdr.what(f.name)
    image_name = f.name

newMessage.add_attachment(image_data, maintype='image', subtype=image_type, filename=image_name)

# Send E-mail
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(sender, password)
    smtp.send_message(newMessage)
```